# Gradle build finished with error(s)

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I just installed android studio on my laptop. When I run the blank application, it shows the following error:

Gradle build finished with 46 error(s). here is a screenshot showing the errors:

[image]

I would appreciate if anyone could help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Try clean & build project

Answer (score 0):

Find solution, I was using a older version of JDK. I updated to 1.8 and now its working properly